# How to use range-based for_each in Boost.Phoenix?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

Let's consider following code:

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> const small_ints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> const big_ints {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

    namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
    using namespace boost::phoenix;
    using namespace boost::phoenix::placeholders;

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator big_ints_it;
    std::for_each(small_ints.cbegin(), small_ints.cend(),
        for_(phoenix::ref(big_ints_it) = begin(phoenix::cref(big_ints)), phoenix::ref(big_ints_it) != end(phoenix::cref(big_ints)), ++phoenix::ref(big_ints_it))
        [
            std::cout << val('(') << arg1 << ',' << *phoenix::ref(big_ints_it) << "), "
        ]
    );
}
```

It works fine by printing expected sequence of pairs

```
(1,11), (1,12), (1,13), (1,14), (1,15), (2,11), (2,12), …, (5,14), (5,15),
```

which is just Cartesian product resulting from double iteration.

However the `for_` is ugly! Look at all those `ref`, `cref` (that somehow I always have to explicitly select from `phoenix` as otherwise there are conflicts with `std` versions). Not to mention that I have to keep useless `big_ints_it` variable!

Note also that this follows [example provided by Phoenix documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/statement/for_statement.html) itself.

Now I tried to use `for_each` [mentioned along iteration algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/stl/algorithm.html), expecting much simpler version:

```
std::for_each(small_ints.cbegin(), small_ints.cend(),
    for_each(phoenix::cref(big_ints),
        std::cout << val('(') << arg1 << ", " << arg2 << "), "
    )
);
```

but it doesn't even compile! Or at least with Visual Studio 2013 and Boost 1.61.

I'm getting multiple errors. First of which is

```
1>c:\programming\boost_1_61_0\boost\proto\detail\poly_function.hpp(205): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::proto::functional::at::result<Sig>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Sig=boost::proto::functional::at (boost::phoenix::vector2<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval,boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::impl::for_each>,0>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::reference_wrapper<const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>>>,0>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &>,0>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char>,0>>>,2>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1>>,0>>>,2>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [3]>,0>>>,2>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2>>,0>>>,2>>,boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<char [4]>,0>>>,2>>>,3>> *,const int &> &,boost::mpl::int_<2>)
1>          ]
…
```

I cannot even enter the whole first error since StackOverflow says, that question body is limited to 30,000 characters which I have entered 135,034 of them…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `arg2` in your inner expression. Let's have a look at the situation.

You basically have:

```
- for_each(begin,end,outer_expr);
- outer_expr=for_each(begin,end,inner_expr);
```

Both `outer_expr` and `inner_expr` are lambda expression that take a single argument (an element of its respective vectors).

What you need is a way to pass the argument from `outer_expr` to `inner_expr`. Luckily Boost.Phoenix provides an easy way to do just that: [`boost::phoenix::lambda`](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/scope/lambda.html):

```
std::for_each(small_ints.cbegin(), small_ints.cend(),
            phx::for_each(phx::cref(big_ints),
            phx::lambda(_a=arg1)[phx::ref(std::cout) << '(' << _a << ", " << arg1 << "), "]
        )
    );
```

Or getting a little silly, but maybe helping readability:

```
boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg1_type current_small_int, current_big_int;
boost::phoenix::local_names::_a_type passed_small_int;

std::for_each(small_ints.cbegin(), small_ints.cend(),
            phx::for_each(phx::cref(big_ints),
            phx::lambda(passed_small_int=current_small_int)[phx::ref(std::cout) << '(' << passed_small_int << ", " << current_big_int << "), "]
        )
    );
```

Full Sample [(Running on WandBox)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9G064hMAIZUL4yW2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> const small_ints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> const big_ints {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
    using boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg1;
    using boost::phoenix::local_names::_a;

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator big_ints_it;
    std::for_each(small_ints.cbegin(), small_ints.cend(),
        phx::for_each(phx::cref(big_ints),
        phx::lambda(_a=arg1)[phx::ref(std::cout) << '(' << _a << ", " << arg1 << "), "]
    )
    );
}
```

PS: If your compiler can initialize the vectors like that, it should probably be able to use actual lambdas and that would probably result in less headaches.

Comment: Wow! Now that I read your answer I wonder how I could have not seen the obvious problem with `arg2`! What was I thinking?! Thanks!

Comment: Oh! And as to compiler and actual lambdas, you are obviously right. However for my final work I'm stack with old compiler. While the examples to ask question I'm doing in a different compiler.